# YAML syntax for Salt and Python

Tags: python, yaml, salt-stack

What is the diference between this:

```
dic1: 
  - subdict1.1: value11.1
  - subdict1.2: value1.2
  - cubdict1.3: value1.3
```

and This:

```
dict2:
  subdict2.1: value2.2
  subdict2.1: value2.2
  subdict2.3: value2.3
```

I know the first one evaluates to a list of dictionaries. but what is the second one? isn't also a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is just a *nested* dictionary.

**Example**

`YAML` code:

```
first_level_dict_key:
  second_level_dict_key: value_in_second_level_dict
```

*Results* in `Python`:

```
{
    'first_level_dict_key': {
        'second_level_dict_key': 'value_in_second_level_dict'
    }
}
```

Explanation from `salt` [docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/yaml/).

> **RULE TWO: COLONS**
>
> Python dictionaries are, of course, simply key-value pairs. Users from
>   other languages may recognize this data type as hashes or associative
>   arrays.
>
> Dictionary keys are represented in YAML as strings terminated by a
>   trailing colon. Values are represented by either a string following
>   the colon, separated by a space